# Using Moq to override virtual methods in the same class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

We are using Moq to unit test our service classes, but are stuck on how to test situations where a service method calls another service method of the same class.  I tried setting the method being called to virtual, but still couldn't figure out what to do then in Moq.  For example:

```
public class RenewalService : IRenewalService
{
    //we've already tested this
    public virtual DateTime? GetNextRenewalDate(Guid clientId)
    {
        DateTime? nextRenewalDate = null;
        //...<snip> a ton of already tested stuff...

        return nextRenewalDate;
    }

    //but want to test this without needing to mock all 
    //the methods called in the GetNextRenewalDate method
    public bool IsLastRenewalOfYear(Renewal renewal)
    {
        DateTime? nextRenewalDate = GetNextRenewalDate(renewal.Client.Id);
        if (nextRenewalDate == null)
            throw new Exceptions.DataIntegrityException("No scheduled renewal date, cannot determine if last renewal of year");
        if (nextRenewalDate.Value.Year != renewal.RenewDate.Year)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the above example, our GetNextRenewalDate method is pretty complicated, and we've already unit tested it.  However, we want to test the simpler IsLastRenewalOfYear without needing to mock everything needed for GetNextRenewalDate.  Basically, we just want to mock GetNextRenewalDate.

I realize that I could create a new class that overrides GetNextRenewalDate and test the new class, but is there a way that I can leverage Moq to make this simpler?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can probably use partial mocking in this scenario, although all your methods would need to be virtual:

```
    var mock = new Moq.Mock<RenewalService>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.GetNextRenewalDate(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(null);
    mock.CallBase = true;
    var results = mock.Object.IsLastRenewalOfYear(...);
```

Comment: This seems to work ... I didn't even need to make everything virtual (I just kept it the same as above).

Comment: @Andrew. The above works because `Mock.CallBase == true` means that invocations that are not matched by a setup will call the underlying implementation. So, `IsLastRenewalOfYear` will call the implementation, because it's not virtual, but `GetNextRenewalDate` will return `null` because the setup will always be matched. The following code will work even if `IsLastRenewalOfYear` **is** virtual.

Comment: we used this in a couple other places too, worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: What about a situation where the `mock.Object` requires a contructor?

An error is given when executing the method:
Can not instantiate proxy of class: (classNameGoesHere).
Could not find a parameterless constructor.
Parameter name: constructorArguments

Comment: @MattyBear Mock<RenewalService>("Blah Blah")

Answer (score 4):

```
var mock = new Moq.Mock<RenewalService> { CallBase = true };
mock.Setup(m => m.GetNextRenewalDate(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(null);
var results = mock.Object.IsLastRenewalOfYear(...);
```