# Verifying a method was called without using IoC

Tags: .net, unit-testing

Is it possible to test in .NET that a method was called. The requirements are 1) not using IoC, 2) not writing stubs, etc. manually (but testing framework can be used).

E.g.,

```
public class MyClass {

    public virtual void F1() {
     // Some code
    }

    public virtual void F2() {
     // Some code plus
     this.F1(); // -> I want to test F2 logic as a unit test but I want to make sure F1 is called
    }

}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Of course it's *possible*. What are you actually trying to accomplish with this test? You write unit tests for your code's expected behavior. If your code is doing the correct things, the implementation details are totally irrelevant in the context of unit testing.

Comment: Actually, I found the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539278/using-moq-to-override-virtual-methods-in-the-same-class