# Moq setup not working when using abstract class for unit test

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I want to moq `IsAdult` method in the base abstract class `Person` using Moq/Nunit. Whenever I run the test it calls the actual method `IsAdult` in the base `Person` class instead of returning the value in the setup. My code looks like below

```
 public abstract class Person
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsAdult()
    {
        return this.Age >= 18;
    }

    protected Person(string gender, int age)
    {
        this.Gender = gender;
        this.Age = age;
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    public Employee() : base("Male", 17)
    {
    }

    public string ProcessSalary()
    {
        if (IsAdult())
        {
            // process the salary
            return "Processed";
        }

        return null;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class PersonTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Some_Name()
    {
        var person = new Mock<Person>() { CallBase = true };
        person.Setup(x => x.IsAdult()).Returns(true);

        var employee = new Employee();
        var result = employee.ProcessSalary();

        Assert.AreEqual("Processed", result);
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this setup?

Comment: I don't see where you use of `person`... Or you expect some magic to replace base class with mock????

Comment: (Correct implementation is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539278/using-moq-to-override-virtual-methods-in-the-same-class - if that is where your misunderstanding is - please close as duplicate), otherwise think about what you actually need to be explained and edit post accordingly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  I m mocking base class by creating a mock instance of it and by using that mock instance I m trying to setup a virtual method of that base class to return a particular value.  See the updated question, I need to test `ProcessSalary` method which uses base class `IsAdult` method which I m trying to setup.

Comment: Sample shown is not "using that mock instance" - it is creating completely unrelated instance of `Employee` which knows absolutely nothing about mocked person. I suspect you have some strange ideas about inheritance, but I don't know what exactly can help you to clarify that... Side note: there is a good chance that `ProcessSalary` should not be member of `Employee` but rather take one as parameter (but that is not related to this question)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I would expect that some dose of etiquette in online communication would be very appropriate for person officially representing Microsoft in this venue - unless your profile is not what it says. Quite openly you violate rules set by Microsoft itself for their open source repos to which I contribute. It would be surprising if they would be unique for open source repos only. Being in error and asking questions is just being a human.

Comment: @JacekBlaszczynski Thank you. If you mean that I should have put quotes around "Why don't you try the following" as it was directly copied from your post - yes, I did not do that, will try to be better at that in the future. If it is something else - please let me know (or start meta question since it would be more appropriate to discuss there). Also don't forget that you should flag offensive comment to  be removed by moderators.

Answer (score 2):

```
using Moq;
using Xunit;

namespace MockAbstractClass
{
    public class EmployeeTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void IsAdultMock()
        {
            var employeeMock = new Mock<Employee>() { CallBase = false };
            employeeMock.Setup(x => x.IsAdult()).Returns(true);

            var employee = employeeMock.Object;
            var result = employee.IsAdult();
            Assert.True(result);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Some_Name()
        {
            var employeeMock = new Mock<Employee>() { CallBase = true };
            employeeMock.Setup(x => x.IsAdult()).Returns(true);

            var employee = employeeMock.Object;
            var result = employee.ProcessSalary();

            Assert.Equal("Processed", result);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of mocking up Person mock Employee.IsAdult property. Now everything works as expected.

Comment: Why don't you try the following - [edit] the post to explain how suggested change works from your point of view? (As there is absolutely no difference between sample in the question and this post in relation to the  problem OP has)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You were right I messud up answer. Now is corrected and working as expected.