# Why does calling someMockInstance.Object call constructor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit

Sorry if this is really obvious...

I'm trying to understand why calling `someMockInstance.Object` calls the class constructor.

Here's an example:

```
public class Foo
{
  public Foo()
  {
    // Init some stuff
  }
  
  public virtual string DoSomething()
  {
    // Blah
  }
}
```

```
public class BarTest
{
  [Fact]
  public void SomeMethod()
  {
    var mockFoo = new Mock<Foo>();
    mockFoo.Setup(m => m.DoSomething()).Returns("SomeValue");

    // This causes a call to `Foo.Foo()`
    var result = new Bar(mockFoo.Object).SomeMethod();

    result.Should().Be(true);
  }
}
```

And I guess as importantly, can we avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: You're mocking a concrete class (rather than an interface). To do this, Moq will dynamically create a class which subclasses `Foo`. However, subclasses always need to call a constructor on their base class, and so this dynamically-created subclass will call `Foo`'s parameterless constructor

Comment: Awesome explanation- thanks a mill @canton7 . Did you want to post as an answer- so I can accept?

Comment: @LeeTickett Do you want partial mocking? If so, please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539278/using-moq-to-override-virtual-methods-in-the-same-class)

Comment: @PeterCsala we already do this in places- thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure the call happens on `mockFoo.Object` and not on `new Mock<Foo>()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mocking a concrete class (rather than an interface). To do this, Moq will dynamically create a class which subclasses `Foo`.

However, subclasses always need to call a constructor on their base class, and so this dynamically-created subclass will call `Foo`'s parameterless constructor. This is a rule imposed by the .NET runtime which Moq cannot break.