# Using Moq to mock HttpClient in the context of Thread

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working on creating unit tests using [moq](https://github.com/moq/moq) and I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply this framework to a portion of my program that deals with using an `HttpClient`. There's various resources I found that demonstrate how to mock an `HttpClient` response directly but the way my application makes use of `HttpClient` is slightly different with the utilization of `Thread`s.

The test's skeleton:

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    public void myTest()
    {
        ClassA classObj = new ClassA();
        classObj.Start();
        // I'd like to use moq somewhere here to mock the response that occurs in DoThreadStuff() below
    }
}
```

The class under testing:

```
public class ClassA
{
    private readonly Thread _myThread; 
    private HttpClient _client;
    
    public ClassA()
    {
        // initialize some values
        _myThread = new Thread(DoThreadStuff);
    }
        
    public void Start()
    {
        _myThread.Start(); // starts DoThreadStuff()
    }
    
    private void DoThreadStuff()
    {
        var newClient = getNewHttpClient(); // utility function returns a HttpClient
        var response = newClient.GetAsync("/my/api/status/endpoint");
    }       
}
```

As you can see, when `ClassA.Start()` gets called, a new `HttpClient` gets created and used via `GetAsync`. What would the correct way to structure a test for this look like? Will I have to change the implementation of my existing classes to accommodate for Moq? Does anyone have experience with something very similar which I could take a look at?

Comment: You need to mock the `getNewHttpClient` method to return a properly setup HttpClient mock. Other then that your use case is not so different from others.

Comment: You could inject some factory for the creation of the httpclient, that way you can mock the factory (and thus the httpclient itself).

Comment: @IsaacPerez Could you please share with us the code of `getNewHttpClient`?

Comment: @PeterCsala `getNewHttpClient()` just returns some basic HttpClient object that is then used for the `getAsync()` call that follows. I think the internals of `getNewHttpClient()` are irrelevant.

Comment: @IsaacPerez Okay, then what causing you a problem? If getNewHttpClient is declared as virtual or protected then you can override it to return a properly setup HttpClient mock. Shall I post a sample code for that?

Comment: @PeterCsala sure, please do. I don't think I understand

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that your `ClassA` looks like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    private readonly Thread _myThread;

    public ClassA()
    {
        _myThread = new Thread(DoThreadStuff);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _myThread.Start();
    }

    private void DoThreadStuff()
    {
        var newClient = getNewHttpClient();

        var response = newClient.GetAsync("https://httpstat.us//200").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
        else if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            Console.WriteLine("Not good");
    }

    protected virtual HttpClient getNewHttpClient()
    {
        return new HttpClient();
    }
}
```

- For the sake of testability I've added some dummy code after the `getNewHttpClient` call

  - Please note that calling an async method in sync fashion (`.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`) is not really a good idea
- I've also added the `getNewHttpClient` to your class as `protected virtual` to be able to overwrite it easily

---

Now let's create a helper method to be able to mock an HttpClient:

```
public static HttpClient SetupMockClient(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var mockMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
    mockMessageHandler.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .ReturnsAsync(response);
    return new HttpClient(mockMessageHandler.Object);
}
```

Let's derive from the `ClassA` to override the `getNewHttpClient` method

```
internal class VerifiableClassA : ClassA
{
    private HttpClient mockedHttpClient;
    public VerifiableClassA(HttpClient mockedHttpClient)
    {
        this.mockedHttpClient = mockedHttpClient;
    }

    protected override HttpClient getNewHttpClient()
    {
        return this.mockedHttpClient;
    }
}
```

Please note that you can do [this with moq as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539278/using-moq-to-override-virtual-methods-in-the-same-class) so you don't need to introduce a new class just for testing. But in that case the `getNewHttpClient` should be `public`.

---

Now you can perform unit testing like this:

```
var mockedClient = SetupMockClient(new HttpResponseMessage
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
    Content = new StringContent("Failure")
});

var sut = new VerifiableClassA(mockedClient);
sut.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. I followed your design and am hitting an exception when I call `getAsync()`. The exception message is "Thread was being aborted." and the ExceptionState is "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack". I spent an hour googling and don't know how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: @IsaacPerez I've created a simple .NET 5 console app and the above code works fine without any problem. I don't know how do you use my code so I don't know what could cause that exception.

Comment: @IsaacPerez Are you running the code inside an ASP.NET application? It is not a solution just a workaround to see whether the mocking works as expected: catch (ThreadAbortException ex) { _myThread.ResetAbort(); }

Answer (score -2):

You should consider to use a Factory/Repository-Pattern. They make it easier to Test your methods because you can just inject mocks of objects like HttpClient. The answer Peter Csala suggested is pretty dirty because you create a class that has the single purpose to be used in a test.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).