# Is Mock Possible for a public method which does not have an interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a C# class and it does not inherits any interface.
The method definition is :

```
public HashSet<string> GetInfo (string file, HashSet<string> set)
{
..
}
```

Now, I do not want to test this method but do something like when this method is called, give me a static set with certain values. I am very new to unit testing. How is this possible or is it not possible ? I was thinking of having Moq, but I read it will only help if you have interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot do this without modifying the code you either need to have an interface and than all classes that use this class need to actually bind to the interface so you can pass mock to them. You can think about a mock as an instance of dynamically created type that implements the interface so to pass it anywhere it must be accepted.

The other way would be to make the method virtual this is less invasive as you only need to modify the class itself. Than mock can inherit from this class and override the method with your implementation. The benefit of this is you actually can pass instance of derived class to a method that accepts base class so it will work.

[try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539278/using-moq-to-override-virtual-methods-in-the-same-class)